# Create a Future from an other Future "value" in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-async

I have some difficulty to wrap a function that returns a `Future`.

I have the following code :

```
class Foo {
    Bar data;
}
Future<Foo> getFutureFoo() {...}
```

I'm would like to create a wrapper that directly returns a `Future<Bar>`

```
Future<Bar> getFutureFooBar() {
    var foo_future = getFutureFoo();
    ???
    return bar_future;
}
```

Is there some kind of future transformer like for `Stream`s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future<Bar> getFutureFooBar() async {
      Foo foo_future = await getFutureFoo();
      //use the  foo object to create the Bar object
      return bar_future;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is working - I have a bit of a struggle with the async / await syntax - I will stick to po future for now.

Comment: ... Change my mind - since I will do some more Dart, I will start to use async / await